# Is it possible to report a virus distributor?

Tags: virus

A friend of mine recently fell victim to a hybrid keylogger+remote access virus. The creator of the virus was kind enough to hard-code his/her IP address into the virus itself.

Is it possible to report the virus creator to his/her ISP, and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: You think that ip address is a personal address of the hacker? or a remote ip to a server they have also hacked, that is owned by someone else?  Smart enough to infect that PC but not smart enough to cover their tracks?, I don't think so.

Comment: @Moab: No, I don't think it's the personal address of the hacker. It's where victims' account details are sent. Or so Wireshark and a disassembly have led me to believe.

Comment: @Moab: Personal address or no, I still think I owe it to the ISP to let them know their services are being used for illegal activity.

Comment: Do what you think is right, Wil posted the information you need to contact them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is...

Go to [www.whois.sc](http://www.whois.sc) and type the IP address.

It should allow you to find out the country of origin, ISP and abuse contact details as well as a few other bits of information.

However, I doubt this will go anywhere.

(depending how technical you are) In addition, you may want to do your own information gathering - try connecting over HTTP default ports (I wouldn't recommend further than this  as you do not want to get in to hacking) and just see if it responds - you may get lucky and see "enough" information if they are hosting any websites.

Comment: The IP doesn't seem to be in use for anything other than harvesting account details. It may even be a proxy, I'm not sure. I'll contact the ISP, although I don't hold much hope. It's frustrating that this guy is probably going to get away with it thanks to the anonymity of the internet.